# Microsoft Office 2013 App Building

Tags: ms-office, bing-maps

I've never worked on Office Apps before nor have I ever used an API before.
All I want is to develop an Office App for Microsoft Office 2013. I would like to use Bing Maps or Bing Image Search in it. Can anybody guide me through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation on how to create Office apps here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220082.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220065.aspx

Since this is just HTML and JavaScript you can easily use the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control to add maps. You can find documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

You can also find an interactive SDK here: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#CreateMap1